# RLANG - graphs in SAS with R script vanishes

Tags: r, sas, rlang

I am trying to plot a graph with R script in SAS as below

```
proc iml; 
run exportdatasettoR("work.demo","ty");

submit / R; 
attach(ty)
boxplot(age)
endsubmit;
quit;
```

However the graphs appears for just a second and vanishes, where do I find the graph or is there any system setting I need look for?